# generate sample of numbers within range random amount of times in chronological order

Tags: python, random, repeat

I have a list of 5000 ids, and I want to generate a number between

```
ids = range(1,5000)
ids = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 1) for x in ids))
```

I want to add a new column with a number in chronological order between 1 and 50 per id. The number should occur a semi random amount of times, for instance like this

The expected output should be something like

```
a = [1] * 10
b = [2] * 32
c = [3] * 98
d = [4] * 239
e = [5] * 187
.... 
xx = [50] * 2876
```

but i am sure there must be a better way

Thank you!

Comment: I have understood the part where you say that you want to generate random numbers between 1 and 5000. But, I cannot comprehend the second part. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not comprehend your problem completely but I have a piece of code which I made by what I have understood.

```
import random
random_list =[]
for i in range(1,51):
    ids = random.randint(1,5001)
    random_list.append(ids)
    random_list.sort()
print (random_list)
for j in range(0,50):
    
    print(f"[{j+1}] * {random_list[j]}")
```